# how to render loginpage before ngview in angularjs as it is spa

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to Angular J's and want to apply security in application so want log-in page as my default page of my application, my application is single page application.?

Comment: Are you asking if you application is a single page application? Please show what you have tried, show examples, and explain your problem

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this tutorial on ng-view: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-ng-view
It shows how to set up basic routing in angular. Don't forget to include the routing directive first.

Alternatively you can always do an easy html "login only" page and then redirect after authentication. This might even be smarter for big applications cause you won't load all the AngularJS stuff before the user is authenticated.